# MySQL INSERT - SELECT syntax problem!

Tags: sql, mysql, select, insert

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table3
(id1,   id2) VALUES
SELECT id1, id2 FROM table1, table2;
```

What's wrong with the above SQL query?

It shows me **syntax error**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the word `VALUES`. [See here for spec](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table3
(id1,   id2) 
SELECT id1, id2 FROM table1, table2;
```

And note Russ' response.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately i did not care about it. :(

Comment: @Saiful: what is this *it* that you refer to?

Comment: can't they relax this rule, made me go mad

Answer (score 2):

Remove "VALUES".

Oh, and by the way, you've got a cartesian join.   You should add syntax to join table1 to table2.

Comment: +1 for catching
 the cartesian join. That could cause a lot of pain... unless OP actually *wants* that...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table3(id1,   id2) 
SELECT id1, id2 FROM table1, table2;
```

`VALUES` is not used in combination with a `SELECT` statement